# Convention for Javascript Domain Model Objects

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

If I have to create a domain model object in C# I might do something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    Public string Name { get; set; }
    Public string Gender { get; set; }
    Public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

In Javascript, what is the convention for defining such objects? I'm thinking something like this:

```
NAMESPACE.Person = function() {
    this.name = "";
    this.gender = "";
    this.age = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, spot on basically. The only thing to add is that you should **prototype methods** on. How you proto can be situational to the design, I generally prefer to do this internally to the class, but flagged so it only runs when required, and only the once.

```
NAMESPACE.Person = function() {
    this.name = "";
    this.gender = "";
    this.age = 0;

    if(!NAMESPACE.Person._prototyped)
    {
        NAMESPACE.Person.prototype.MethodA = function () {};
        NAMESPACE.Person.prototype.MethodB = function () {};
        NAMESPACE.Person.prototype.MethodC = function () {};

        NAMESPACE.Person._prototyped = true; 
    }
}
```

Explaining why: The reason for this is performance and inheritance. Prototyped properties are directly associated with the class (function) object rather than the instance, so they are traversable from the function reference alone. And because they are on the class, only a single object needs to exist, not one per instance.

Comment: would it be NAMESPACE.Person._prototyped, or NAMESPACE.Person.prototype._prototyped

Comment: I doubt there's a real benefit to defer prototype members initialization and it clutters the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is much of a "convention" but you can declare "private" variables and Crockford shows you how to [here](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html)

> ```
> function Constructor(...) { var that =
> this; var membername = value; function
> membername(...) {...}
>
> }
> ```
>
> Note: The function statement
>
> ```
> function membername(...) {...}
> ```
>
> is shorthand for
>
> ```
> var membername = function
> membername(...) {...};
> ```

To round out the answer, you would do this, you'll notice I do it a little differently

```
// class
function Person()
{
    // private variable
    var name = "Default Value";

    // getter
    this.getName = function()
    {
        return name;
    }

    // setter
    this.setName = function(s)
    {
        name = s;
    }
}


// instanciate an object
var p = new Person();

// alerts: Default Value
alert(p.getName());

p.setName("def");

// alerts: def
alert(p.getName());

// alerts: undefined
alert(p.name);
```